# take variable from os.system and return in bottle

Tags: python-3.x, bottle

firstly. Thank you for any assistance you can provide on this. I really appreciate it.

As a home project i want a temp readout to display in bottle. Once i understand this process i intend to up the refresh rate using a simple loop.

The bit i am struggling to understand is taking the two variables from os.system and then referencing them in my return statement. I am struggling to find online documentation that i can learn from.

from bottle import route, run, template

```
import os
import Adafruit_DHT

@route('/temp') 
def temp():
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)
    return Temp={0:0.1f}*C  Humidity={1:0.1f}%'.format(temperature, humidity)

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Comment: Why do you think ``os.system()`` is needed at all?  That's for running external commands, the code you have inside the quotes is something you'd do directly in Python.  You've made a similar mistake with your ``return`` statement - instead of actually executing the code, you're returning a string containing the code.

Comment: Thanks Jason, really appreciate your help. I have updated it now as above. I am getting an invalid syntax error now starting from the = after Temp.

Comment: You removed too many quote marks - the start of the expression you're returning is supposed to be a string, to which you apply the ``format()`` method to fill in the values.

Comment: Ah OK, that makes sense.Thank you, it is working now. I think it is evident i need to revisit Python basics.